# SeekBar progressDrawable fitXY

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have a SeekBar with a progressDrawable.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In this seekbar I used the image.png

[image]

My phone's screen is bigger, than this image. So I want to use this image like "fitXY" .

Actually it's multiply the image.
[image]

How can I set the image to match_parent?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you need to update the black portion ? As the seekbar goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Drawble folder**
seekbar_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:left="300dip">
            <shape
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#0000FF" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:right="400dip">
            <shape
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Can I specify it in percent?

Comment: @vihkat yes you can!

Comment: @vihkat you want to specify percentage as a programmatically [use this class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17630726/2794507)

Comment: Thank you! I chose this programmatically solution. This is the best I think for every screen!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch).

I just made it in paint, so probably there is some error, but hope you get the idea. Also you can make image smaller, to reduce its size.

[image: example.9.png]